# How do you call two parabolas sharing a directrix line but having different palces on the plane.

Tags: geometry

They may be quite the same: $x^2$ and $x^2+c$ and quite different: $x^2$ and $ax^2+c$. Do they have a certain special name or do they not? They are not parallael for sure. Neither the first ones nor the second. I call them codirectional. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've read it, but I can't ask the question the other way. I'm poor at english. Does your reminder mean I'll scarcely get an answer? Sorry. Then you have to delete my inquiry.

Comment: If $y=x^2$ and $y=x^2+c$ are examples, then it would appear that by "sharing a directrix line" you actually mean "having parallel directrices" (or, perhaps better, "having parallel axes"). I don't know of a specific name for such parabolas. Of course, you're free to assign any name you like; just make sure to define the usage for your readers. ... Now, "codirectional" doesn't seem the best fit for a family that includes $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$. On the other hand, if the parabolas in your family must also "open" in the same way relative to their directrices, "codirectional" is a pretty good term.

Comment: @SimpletonJack I wrote **nothing** about the way of asking your question. I only wrote about typing those mathematical symbols.

Comment: $x^2$ and $x^2+c$ and $ax^2+c$ do not share their directrix (directrices?) but do share their axis of symmetry

Comment: I said no directrix or directrice simply I said a directrix line. That's the difference.

Comment: And the axis of symmetry may be indeed at any angle not only the axis symmetrical.